# SendGrid: Is it possible to have a custom unsubscription page instead of using sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, unsubscribe

I know we can add a unsubscribed link in the template so when sending email there will be unsubscribed link at the bottom. It will show the preferences page. This page is created by sendgrid.

Is there a way to create our own unsubscribed screen instead? That way if someone modified their email in our system we can have control the unsubscription.

Answer (score -3):

There are two things possible;

1. If you would like to use a custom URL for your unsubscribe link, from the Editor, navigate to Settings in the left-hand sidebar and select the Recipients dropdown menu. Under **Unsubscribe Group**, select **Use Custom Link**...
   This will expand a new field where you can insert a URL for one of your own pages where recipients can manage their subscription preferences.
   To place your Custom Unsubscribe link into your email, highlight any text within the body of your email and click the small link icon to specify a hyperlink. In the URL field that appears, enter the tag `{{{unsubscribe}}}`. Since you've specified your Custom Unsubscribe Link in the Settings panel, SendGrid will replace the Unsubscribe Tag with your custom URL.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/create-and-manage-unsubscribe-groups#using-a-custom-unsubscribe-link

2. List unsubscribe: email to get unsubscribe email, later you can do it manually or automatically

- **With CSV**

1. Find the group you want to add recipients to and click the action menu.[image]
2. Select **Upload a CSV**.
3. Drag the CSV you want to upload into the field, or click **select a CSV file to upload** and locate the file you want to upload from your files.
   4.Click **Upload CSV**.

- **Manually**

1. Find the group you want to add recipients to and click the action menu.
2. Select **Manually Add**.
3. Enter a recipient email address and then click **Save**.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/create-and-manage-unsubscribe-groups#add-recipients-to-an-unsubscribe-group

Comment: Thank you... The first link is designed for Marketing Campaign sending.. Does the Template design has similar functionality.